# Merging all files in a folder with an avidemux batch file

Tags: software

I`ve been trying to create a batch file that merges all files in a folder using avidemux. Ideally, it would be awesome if this works to do some changes as well (basically rescaling the video).

I have tried with this .bat file but it does not do what I intended:

```
set avidemux="C:\Program Files\Avidemux 2.7 VC++ 64bits\avidemux.exe"

set videocodec=mp4

for %%f in (*.mp4) do %avidemux% --video-codec %videocodec% --force-alt-h264 --load "%%f" --append "%%f" --save "%%f.avi" --quit
```

What this does is just open each file individually and save it individually, not actually merging them.

If there are any one-click solutions for this kind of issue it would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a solution using `ffmpeg` instead of `avidemux`. I made the following batch file. In this case, I had to know the folder where the ffmpeg executable was, and also i managed to convert the resolution to a different one

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    echo file %%f >> list.txt
)
F:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -vf scale=320:240 output.avi
del list.txt
```

This did the trick!

Comment: This is based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922352/how-can-i-merge-all-the-videos-in-a-folder-to-make-a-single-video-file-using-ffm

Comment: If this solves your problem perfectly, then please mark your answer as accepted (click the check mark on the left).